# Return only row where value of Col A is not found in Col B for rows with a given value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to return only 5678 in this example, because it does not exist in column B for the rows with 5678 in column A.

```
col_a   col_b
1234    1234
1234    5678
5678    3321
5678    3135
```

Comment: RJ- that would return 1234.  I want to return 5678 because that value isn't in col_b for the two rows containing 5678 in col_a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct t.col_a from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where col_a = t.col_a and col_b = t.col_a
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42dd4a1f8c7a5b849cda7a77eb2e65e7).
Result:

```
| col_a |
| ----- |
| 5678  |
```

Or you can `group by col_a` and set a condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select col_a 
from tablename 
group by col_a
having sum(case when col_a = col_b then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce5fc78017346d4c0230a869ac5a552d).

Comment: ` HAVING SUM(case HA.CIFInternal = MP.Member_NBR then 1 else 0 end) = 0 `  Do you know why this isn't working?  Microsoft SQL doesn't like the = in the case statement..

Comment: I updated the demos for SQL Server and they both work. Check them.

Comment: You missed WHEN in the case statement

Comment: `HAVING SUM(case when HA.CIFInternal = MP.Member_NBR then 1 else 0 end) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

With **EXCEPT**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col_a FROM tablename
EXCEPT SELECT col_a FROM tablename WHERE col_a = col_b
```

A little more concise, but no more efficient than forpas's method using NOT EXISTS